# Image from sql database not showing on PHP

Tags: php, sql, image, show

I have this code on php:

```
$query = "select * from product";
$result = mysql_query($query);
 <?php

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['ProductName']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Price']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Stock']. "</td>";
    echo "<td><img src=photos/'". $row['ProductImage']. "'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
   }
  ?>
```

But the images from the sql database won't be shown. It only appear like the image I attached. [image: Products Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for broken images, check the source code / the image URL in the page to check you're getting the right HTML. In your case,

`echo "<td><img src=photos/'". $row['ProductImage']. "'/></td>";`

This is going to show up as `<img src=photos/'productimage.png'/>` for example. The `'` needs to encapsulate the `photos/` part too to be valid.

Change

```
echo "<td><img src=photos/'". $row['ProductImage']. "'/></td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td><img src='photos/". $row['ProductImage']. "'/></td>";
```

and assuming that the URL is correct then, it will work.